# Query to list all available databases in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Is it possible to list information about all databases in DB2 database?

In SQL server, `select * from sys.databases` will shows information about each database.

Similarly, is there any query available in DB2 database?

Comment: Is this for LUW or z/OS?

Answer (score 2):

You can do [LIST DATABASE DIRECTORY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001961.html) in Db2 to get a list of all cataloged databases. Databases are a slightly different concept in Db2 than in SQL Server.

It is a [CLP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc-gentopic2.html) command and not regular SQL.